# uitableview: nothing is displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm creating an app where it should connect to an sql database ad display its content in a table view cell. I have made the connection to the database and it works now fine, nevertheless, it does not display anything in the tableview and I cannot understand why it's not functioning well. the code is below if you may help me:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"test");
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=[self.entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

it doesn't even display any static if I do this

```
 cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"test";
```

any suggestions? thanks in advance.

Comment: check if you have properly connected delegate and datasource of tableview

Comment: Examine the contents of the `entries` array and confirm you have the values there which you expect.

Comment: Have you tried debugging?  Does control reach your `cellForRow...` method at all?  Is `cell` non-nil?

Comment: did you add - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section?

Comment: thank you folks for your hints. answering you one by one: 1- I have checked the datasource and delegate connections all indicated to the view. 2- numberOfRowsInSection is added but it doesn't show anything -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [entries count];
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[entries count]);
} it even says code will never be executed...

Comment: Dear all, I still cannot find the problem, any other suggestions. I added NSLog to see if the code gets executed and it doesn't as it seems that could be the problem what did I do wrong here I cannot comprehend, @AshishMusale; @NullData; @HotLicks

Comment: You need to add NSLog before the return statement to see the number of entries